# Collapsible & Expandable row with dynamic content based on cell

Tags: javascript, html, css, confluence

I am trying to enhance our confluence dashboard for database loading statuses, and I would like to have the following behavior on table, with collapsible/expandable rows, to display content.

Default State

[image: Deafult state]

Clicking on row `iud_2` expands the hidden content

[image: Aux Details]

But based on which cell, the hidden content changes. The above shown when clicked on Aux column's `In Progress` text.

Below when clicked on Core column's `Not Started` text.

[image: Core Details]

And last example when clicked on `iud_3` row's Stage column's `OK` text.

[[image: Stage Details4]

I have come across https://github.com/chhikaradi1993/Expandable-table-row/blob/master/index.html this functionality, which serves well and simple for expanding the row.

```
  <script>
    const toggleRow = (element) => {
      element.getElementsByClassName('expanded-row-content')[0].classList.toggle('hide-row');
      console.log(event);
    }
  </script>
```

But changing the content in the hidden row dynamically seems to be challenging without external libraries.

I am wondering if I can achieve this in minimal CSS/JS since this is embedded in standard confluence page, and I am unable to have addons installed.

Is something like this possible with few lines of JS? Guidance to the right resources would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your environment (which I'm not accustomed to) I'm not sure how much space for development you got, but anyways you could use a bit of CSS and a small JavaScript that gets the clicked cell index, and targets the next row's TD (with the same index) and sets `colspan` to i.e: `4` and toggles its `display` property:

```js
const toggleRow = (ev) => {
  const elClickedTD = ev.target.closest("td");
  const indexTD = elClickedTD.cellIndex;
  const elNextTr = ev.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
  elNextTr.querySelectorAll("td").forEach((elTD, idx) => {
    elTD.style.display = idx === indexTD ? "table-cell" : "none";
    elTD.setAttribute("colspan", 4);
  });
};

document.querySelectorAll(".table-expand tbody tr:nth-child(odd)").forEach(elTr => {
  elTr.addEventListener("click", toggleRow);
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 1rem/1.3 sans-serif;
}

.table-expand {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: none;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-expand th {
  background: #305496;
  color: #fff;
}

.table-expand td,
.table-expand th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.table-expand tbody tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background: #eee;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-expand">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Database</th>
      <th>Stage</th>
      <th>Aux</th>
      <th>Core</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>iud_1</td>
      <td>OK</td>
      <td>In progress</td>
      <td>Not started</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1Database desc...</td>
      <td>1Stage desc...</td>
      <td>1Aux desc...</td>
      <td>1Core desc...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>iud_1</td>
      <td>OK</td>
      <td>OK</td>
      <td>Error</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2Database desc...</td>
      <td>2Stage desc...</td>
      <td>2Aux desc...</td>
      <td>2Core desc...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>iud_1</td>
      <td>OK</td>
      <td>OK</td>
      <td>OK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3Database desc...</td>
      <td>3Stage desc...</td>
      <td>3Aux desc...</td>
      <td>3Core desc...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

To toggle the colspans, I would advise using `.classList` to modify a `.is-active` class on a clicked `TD` and use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to handle the rest, like toggling a `.is-collapsed` to the next row's cell:

```js
const expandObserver = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach(mut => {
    const elTD = mut.target;
    const elTR = elTD.closest("tr");
    const indexTD = elTD.cellIndex;

    const elNextTR = elTR.nextElementSibling;
    const elNextTD = elNextTR.querySelectorAll("td")[indexTD];
    const isActive = elTD.classList.contains("is-active");

    elNextTD.setAttribute("colspan", 4);
    elNextTD.classList.toggle("is-expanded", isActive);
  });
});

document.querySelectorAll(".table-expand tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td").forEach(elTD => {

  expandObserver.observe(elTD, {
    attributes: true,
    attributeFilter: ["class"],
  });

  elTD.addEventListener("pointerdown", () => {
    const elTDCurrentActive = elTD.closest(".table-expand").querySelector("td.is-active");
    if (elTDCurrentActive && elTD !== elTDCurrentActive) {
      elTDCurrentActive.classList.remove("is-active");
    }
    elTD.classList.toggle("is-active");
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  font: 1rem/1.3 sans-serif;
}

.table-expand {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: none;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-expand th {
  background: #305496;
  color: #fff;
}

.table-expand td,
.table-expand th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.table-expand tbody tr:nth-child(even) td {
  display: none;
  background: #eee;
  text-align: center;
}

.table-expand tbody tr:nth-child(even) td.is-expanded {
  display: table-cell;
}

.table-expand td.is-active {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-expand">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Database</th>
      <th>Stage</th>
      <th>Aux</th>
      <th>Core</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>iud_1</td>
      <td>OK</td>
      <td>In progress</td>
      <td>Not started</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1Database desc...</td>
      <td>1Stage desc...</td>
      <td>1Aux desc...</td>
      <td>1Core desc...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>iud_1</td>
      <td>OK</td>
      <td>OK</td>
      <td>Error</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2Database desc...</td>
      <td>2Stage desc...</td>
      <td>2Aux desc...</td>
      <td>2Core desc...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>iud_1</td>
      <td>OK</td>
      <td>OK</td>
      <td>OK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3Database desc...</td>
      <td>3Stage desc...</td>
      <td>3Aux desc...</td>
      <td>3Core desc...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Pretty, works well in my settings. Thanks so much. I will try to combine this with the idea from the linked github, and see if I make it collapse as well as expand on the click. Thank you!

Comment: @jbrezik added another example that toggles (collapses / expands) the colspans with the descriptions. Involved an extended approach, but might be useful in the end.

Comment: That is awesome Roko, exactly what I was looking for with minimal dependencies. Thank you.